# Topology of spinor varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, at.algebraic-topology

I am looking for a reference about the topology of spinor varieties. Is there some place where the Betti numbers, Chern numbers,  cohomology ring etc. of spinor varieties is given (including general formulas, not depending on the dimension)?

Comment: As these are homogeneous varieties, $G/P$, much can be computed from the structure of the Weyl groups of $G$ and $P$.